# Is it possible to request last version of App from Android Market via API to ensure that users have latest version before launch?

Tags: android, google-play

Is it possible to request last version of App from Android Market via API to ensure that users have latest version before launch?

In our application we cannot allow users with old version to continue using our Android app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no API-way.

If it's an app that has internet permission, you can implement an own check for newer versions and simply let the app do nothing if the installed version is not up to date.

It is by design that the user is in charge of what updates he wants to install. the only way for automatic updates is for the user checking "automatic update" in the market.

Answer (score 1):

There is no documented and supported API for the Android Market.

Of course, you are welcome to host your version information on your own Web server and retrieve it from there.